# ASP.NET: Request.Form is slow!

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, iis-7, httpcontext

I have a very strange behavior with **Request.Form**.

Here are two IIS 7 servers running the same ASP.NET application. On the first instance it's all ok. But the second one have very slow performance.

Profiler showed that this line:

```
context.Request.Form["id"]
```

takes more than **130 ms** each time!

Profiler log:

0,60% get_Form - 4536 ms - 68 calls - System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()

Server configurations are just the same (?). The first server runs Vista, the second (slower) runs Windows Web Server 2008.

**UPD:**
Both application instances are running in integrated mode, pool setting are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird... both are running in Integrated mode? all AppPool settings are the same? You might want to post it so someone might be able to help.

Comment: Yes, integrated mode, pool settings are the same. Updated the question.

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880168/asp-net-request-form-performance/

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880168/asp-net-request-form-performance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Just changed the application port from 80 to 8080. I don't know the reasons of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is Request.Form["id"] your only reference to Request.Form during this request? In this case, the time may be related to the overhead of referring to the Form collection. For fun, try adding another reference to Request.Form to see if it also takes 130ms.

Comment: It was a mistake: single Request.Form["id"] takes about 60-65 ms.
If there are 2 references to Request.Form it takes 2 x 65 ms = 130 ms.