# System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest:ReadEntityCoreSync, What is it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I'm not a developer, so please excuse me ignorance in this case. We have an ASP.net webforms application written in C#. The application is served from IIS 8 on Win Server 2012 VM, with 8-core CPU and plenty of RAM. 
Some of application users are complaining about some page stalls.
We have an Application Performance Monitoring system, it is telling me that the below method is taking 30 seconds to execute somtimes.

Name: System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest:ReadEntityCoreSync

Type: .NET Class / Method

Class: System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest

**Method: ReadEntityCoreSync**

I have been trying to look around trying to figure out what is this method all about with no luck, could anyone please tell me what is this method doing, and what could cause it to run for extended period of time?

Comment: It looks like it synchronously reads the entity body http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Hosting/IIS7WorkerRequest.cs#bea360c6267495f5 [This may be related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810616/242520)

Comment: That actually sounds correct, it only happens in a certain page, sometimes the application tries to know which page the user is on to return back to a previous location. thanks a lot for the hint and the link... I will speak to the dev team about it.